# How Route Map direct to .html without controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem, I can't direct display test.html without using controller.

I used this http://localhost.mywebsite/test.html

and this is the error display
[image]

here is my VS studio

[image]

Note: I will not use controller to this display html like

```
 public virtual ActionResult test(Index index)
```

I want is to direct view will pass through controller.

any Idea please? thank you.

Comment: Why are you missing root in your url http://localhost.mywebsite/test.html -> http://localhost.mywebsite/root/test.html?

Comment: I thought you wrongly understand the meaning of root folder. you can put your html file to project folder(root folder). Root folder means your project folder is called as root folder.Don't need to create a folder called root